# Adding removing items from list

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have a simple question. Googled this a lot, but was not able to find a suitable solution. I have a list, based on 5 checkboxes.

abc.html

```
<li id="DisplaySelection">  </li> 
{{form.Test1 }}   //checkbox1 
.... 
{{form.Test5 }}  //checkbox5
```

main.js

```
document.getElementById('Test1').onclick = function() {
    if ( this.checked )  {
        var word = 'Selection1';    
        document.getElementById('DisplaySelection').innerHTML +=   ('<li>'+word+'</li>');
    }
    else {
        //  remove same word from list
    }
}

document.getElementById('Test5').onclick = function() {
    if ( this.checked )  {
        word = 'Selection5';
        document.getElementById('DisplaySelection').innerHTML += ('<li>'+word+'</li>');
     }
     else
         //  remove from list
     }
}
```

I want to accomplish the remove part. That is, if the checkbox is unchecked remove that item from the list. How do I get this working? Yes, I'm new to JavaScript.

Thanks for the answers but the problem is I have Django form fields and not html and I don't know how to add value and class attributes to them.

Comment: provide a fiddle please.

Comment: I cant understand what is do u want exactly, try to put the full example for understand it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want some thing this ....

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
  classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction);
}

function myFunction() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.getElementById('selectedItems').innerHTML += '<li id="' + this.value + '">' + this.value + '</li>';
  } else {
    var elem = document.getElementById(this.value);
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  }
}
```

```html
<h4>Selected Items</h4>
<ul id='selectedItems'>
</ul>
<div>
  <h4>Select Items</h4>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input type='checkbox' value='item1' class='item'>Item1</li>
    <li>
      <input type='checkbox' value='item2' class='item'>Item2</li>
    <li>
      <input type='checkbox' value='item3' class='item'>Item3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
Though M using Django to implement forms , the checkboxes I used are not a part of a list and by default all my checkboxes are already selected, I was able to make some modifications to the above and use it .! It works .

Comment: Happy to help you :)\

Answer (score 0):

```
   else{
       var str= document.getElementById('DisplaySelection').innerHTML;      
       document.getElementById('DisplaySelection').innerHTML = str.Replace("<li>"+word+"</li>","");        

    }
```

try the above code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can not append `li` inside `li` element.

Also note that you must have a unique selector for the `li` which is being appended so that you can use it to remove the element. `cb` class is given to all checkboxes so that we can attach events in `loop`. Also prefer `change` event for `checkboxes` that `click`

Try this example:

```js
var cbElems = document.querySelectorAll('.cb');
var onChnageListener = function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    document.getElementById('DisplaySelection').innerHTML += '<li id="' + this.name + '">' + this.name + '</li>';
  } else {
    var elem = document.getElementById(this.name);
    elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
  }
};
[].forEach.call(cbElems, function(cb) {
  cb.addEventListener('change', onChnageListener);
});
```

```html
<input type='checkbox' name='Test1' class='cb'>
<input type='checkbox' name='Test2' class='cb'>
<input type='checkbox' name='Test3' class='cb'>
<input type='checkbox' name='Test4' class='cb'>
<input type='checkbox' name='Test5' class='cb'>
<ul id="DisplaySelection"></ul>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/p2cf0b8u/)

Answer (score 0):

You should really work it out in another structure.

Start with HTML. Give all checkboxes the same class name and store checked "word" as some data attribute:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-word="For starters: selection #one">
```

Then you will be able to select all checkboxes at once:

```
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
```

Once this is done, you will need to bind click event for all checkboxes in the loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
        var word = this.getAttribute('data-word');
        if (this.checked) {
            selected.push(word);
        } else {
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(word), 1);
        }
        document.getElementById('DisplaySelection').innerHTML = renderSelected();
    });
}
```

Here you can either push new word to the list of selected words or remove it from there.

Finally you just need to render the way you want. This functionality is delegated to separate function, for example:

```
function renderSelected() {
    return '<li>' + selected.join('</li><li>') + '</li>'
}
```

Final result:

```js
var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('.check');
var selected = [];

for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
 checkboxes[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
     var word = this.getAttribute('data-word');
        if (this.checked) {
            selected.push(word);
        } else {
            selected.splice(selected.indexOf(word), 1);
        }
        document.getElementById('DisplaySelection').innerHTML = renderSelected();
    });
}

function renderSelected() {
 return '<li>' + selected.join('</li><li>') + '</li>'
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-word="For starters: selection #one"> For starters <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-word="One more item: another"> One more item <br>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" data-word="Also something else"> Something else <br>

<ul id="DisplaySelection"></aul>
```